# webpack-dev-server proxy to docker container

Tags: docker, proxy, webpack, docker-compose, webpack-dev-server

I have 2 docker containers managed with docker-compose and can't seem to properly use webpack to proxy some request to the backend api.

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/16AGR/frontend:rw
    links:
      - back:back
  back:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    expose:
      - "8080"
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/16AGR/backend:rw
```

the service *web* is a simple react application served by a webpack-dev-server.
the service *back* is a node application.

I have no problem to access either app from my host :

```
$ curl localhost
> index.html
$ curl localhost:8081
> Hello World
```

I can also ping and curl the *back* service from the *web* container :

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
73ebfef9b250        16agr_web           "npm run start"     37 hours ago        Up 13 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp     16agr_web_1
a421fc24f8d9        16agr_back          "npm start"         37 hours ago        Up 15 seconds       0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp   16agr_back_1

$ docker exec -it 73e bash
$ root@73ebfef9b250:/16AGR/frontend# curl back:8080
Hello world
```

However i have a problem with the proxy.
Webpack is started with

```
webpack-dev-server  --display-reasons --display-error-details --history-api-fallback --progress --colors -d --hot --inline --host=0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```

and the config file is

frontend/webpack.config.js :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {
    //redirect api calls to backend server
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: "back:8080",
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

When i try to request /api/test with a link in my app for exemple i get a generic error, the link and google did not help much :(

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/test from localhost to back:8080 (EINVAL) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I suspect some weird thing because the proxy is on the container and the request is on localhost but I don't really have an idea to solve this.

Answer (score 16):

I think I managed to tacle the problem.
Just had to change the webpack configuration with the following

```
  devServer: {
    //redirect api calls to backend server
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: {
          host: "back",
          protocol: 'http:',
          port: 8080
        },
        ignorePath: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nice one! For me, it was the `ignorePath` option that sorted things out. My problem was that requests to other assets, e.g. a background image linked from a stylesheet, were also inheriting the Docker container name, which meant that requests 404'd from the browser. E.g. `http://localhost/path/to/image.png` was getting rewritten to `http://back/path/to/image.png` – which wasn't terribly helpful :)