# Proxying request from webpack 2 using webpack-dev-server to backend api in docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I am trying to proxy my http request to express server running in backend using docker containers but I am getting HTTP 504 in browser console and following error in docker terminal

```
HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/getData from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:3001 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
app:
 build: .
 ports:
     - "8080:8080"
 links:
    - back

back:
  build: ./server
  ports:
   - "3001:3001"
```

I also have 2 docker files for each container 
To run webpack-dev-server 2 in one container I have following Dockerfile

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run","dev"]
```

and my Dockerfile to run container having my express server is

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "run","serve"]
```

Please find a snippet of my webpack.config.js using webpack 2 version and running webpack-dev-server

```
//.... all required dependency for webpack
devServer: {
 host:'0.0.0.0',
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: false,
    proxy: {
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://0.0.0.0:3001",
        "secure": false
      },
    },
    hot:true
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  // ...all required plugins and moduloes for compiling my app
```

I am running my application in package.json using following command

```
"scripts": {
   "serve": "nodemon server/server.js --ignore components",
   "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
}
```

I also referred to following link 
[which uses webpack 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126529/webpack-dev-server-proxy-to-docker-container)
but webpack2 now does not document parameters listed in the link. Also I tried using the additional parameters but it did'nt work.

So does webpack 2 offers any change Origin parameters to proxy a request because I think webpack dev server is considering origin to be same without changeOrigin parameteras in webpack 1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Just posting the answer so it can be use for someone like me. I proxyied my request to container name instead of localhost inside webpack config. Small silly mistakr but it took my whole time to figure out.

```
 proxy: {
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://back:3001", //back is the service name in which my node server is running. refer docker-compose.yml
    "secure": false
  },
},
```